# Get ruby Hash#each to return a built hash

Tags: ruby, hash-map

I'm golfing some code while waiting for a coworker, and I shortened a function to this:

```
def get_data(dir)
  newest = get_most_recent_file_numbers(dir)

  data = {}
  $file_prefixes.each do |type, file_prefix|
    file = File.open("#{dir}/#{file_prefix}_#{newest[type]}.csv")
    file.readline
    data[type] = file.readlines
  end

  data
end
```

**I feel like there must be some method to do away with that last line of just `data`. How can I get `$file_prefixes.each` to return `data`?**

If it matters, `$file_prefixes` looks like this:

```
$file_prefixes = {
  :fixed_deal   => "PC2MMS_CMSS_DEALS_",
  :fixed_offer  => "PC2MMS_CMSS_OFFERS_",
  :mobile_deal  => "PC2MMS_NGBSS_DEALS_",
  :mobile_offer => "PC2MMS_NGBSS_OFFERS_"
}
```

and `newest` is pretty much identical.

My target code might look something like this:

```
def get_data(dir)
  newest = get_most_recent_file_numbers(dir)

  data = {} # might even be able to get rid of this with clever use of Hash.new
  data = $file_prefixes.each do |type, file_prefix|
    file = File.open("#{dir}/#{file_prefix}_#{newest[type]}.csv")
    file.readline
    ???
  end
end
```

*Disclaimer: I'm aware I could golf more by using single letter names, but I'm just trying to get it succinct and still readable*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- Avoid the pattern init + each + update. Use `map` or other functional methods.
- In Ruby >= 2.1.0 you have `Array#to_h`. Use `Hash[...]` in older Rubies.
- Use `File.join`

I'd write:

```
def get_data(dir)
  newest = get_most_recent_file_numbers(dir)
  $file_prefixes.map do |type, file_prefix|
    path = File.join(dir, file_prefix + "_" + newest[type] + ".csv")
    [type, File.readlines(path)]
  end.to_h
end
```

Comment: Hmmm... I need to discard the first line of the file, and I don't see a way to sneak that single readline in here without disrupting your logic. Perhaps I can just set the start for readlines at the first line someway?

Comment: Aha! I can just change that last line to `[type, File.readlines(path)[1,-1]]`. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

[tokland's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64667/1141) is fine, but I thought I'd chime in and suggest using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object) instead of converting your data into an array and back.

```
def get_data(dir)
  newest = get_most_recent_file_numbers(dir)

  $file_prefixes.each_with_object({}) do |mapping, hash|
    file = File.read("#{dir}/#{mapping.first}_#{newest[mapping.last]}
  end
end
```

In this example, I'm just using `each_with_object` to construct a new hash and populate it with values. You can also get rid of the need to call `file = File.open ... file.readlines` by just using `File.read` to get the same output.